# Ordering Validation Constraints in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

Hi working on an admin system.  I want to run the Validation Constraint "NotBlank" *before* running @SecurityAssert\UserPassword.  (otherwise there is unneeded database hit and are two different error messages for the user)  Is this possible?  Thanks!

```
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Validator\Constraints as SecurityAssert; 
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert; 
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;  

class YourClassName

                /**
                 * @Assert\NotBlank( message = "For security reasons, please enter your current password.")
                 * @SecurityAssert\UserPassword(
                 *     message = "Wrong value for your current password"
                 * )
                 */
                protected $oldPassword;
```

Comment: Group sequences may help you with this - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#group-sequence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Qoop said in his comment the use of a [sequence group](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#group-sequence) like the example below could suit your needs:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Validator\Constraints as SecurityAssert; 
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert; 
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

/**
 * @Assert\GroupSequence({"YourClassName", "After"})
 */
class YourClassName

        /**
         * @Assert\NotBlank(
               message = "For security reasons, please enter your current password.")
         * @SecurityAssert\UserPassword(
         *     message = "Wrong value for your current password",
               groups={"After"}
         * )
         */
        protected $oldPassword;
```

Remember to add these validation groups when you build the form.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm also adding the validation groups "Before" and "After" to the related formType but getting the error  "The group "YourClassName" is missing in the group sequence"

Comment: Answer improved... (in the rush I forgot that the sequence needs the entity classname).

Answer (score 2):

If you need a solution for one or two fields you could use [Validation Callback](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html). You just validate a field for specified constraints in the method and call them in your order.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do constraints with priorities with Symfony validator  out of the box. But you can write own wrapper for validation with all features that you need.

See https://github.com/markwilson/symfony2-validator-priority-chain for example.